# struct statement in c, will these 2 make difference?

Tags: c

in c source code, will A and B make difference?

```
typedef struct asdf {
  int aa;
  int bb;
} asdf;

// A
void func1(int a) {
  if(a) return;
  asdf *bb;  
  //****
}

// B
void func1(int a) {
  asdf *bb;  
  if(a) return; // if return here, will bb become a memory leak?
  // ***
}
```

In B, will bb become a memory leak if return when a is true?

Comment: Depends, in C89 , example A is error. But the best for you is to check assembly code.

Comment: Where are you actually allocating the memory for the `asdf`'s?

Comment: @眠りネロク It just added variable to stack.

Comment: If you don't allocate memory you won't have a leak.

Comment: @SchwiftyMcSchwifulface What is actually being allocated on the stack is `bb`.

Comment: @眠りネロク think that's my cue to sleep :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't become a memory leak as there is no dynamic allocation. You need to call `malloc`, or `calloc` without a corresponding `free` to leak memory.

In your code you are just declaring a pointer to a struct.

Comment: You don't even know what OP is asking!

Comment: @tilz0R I have answered the question the OP asked, in B is there a memory leak due to an early return. Please explain how you came to your conclusion?

Comment: OP is asking if there is difference in code execution if `if` statement and variable declaration are swapped. So there is no memory leak as there was no allocation and I don't see a need to allocate anything since variable is never used! Correct answer is the one from haccks.

Comment: @Sato they are not. Check haccks answer for correct answer.

Comment: @Colin__s; That's because of compiler optimization. Since `asdf *bb; ` is not used anywhere in the given snippets so compiler opitimizes the code.

Answer (score 2):

In snippet A, if the conditions `a` becomes true then function will return and `asdf *bb;` will not be reached while in snippet B, `bb` will always be declared independent of the `if`'s condition.

> In B, will bb become a memory leak if return when a is true?

If `bb` is allocated memory dynamically in the code then it will cause memory leak.

An example of memory leak

```
void func1(int a) {
    asdf *bb = malloc(10*sizeof(asdf));  
    if(a) return;
    /* some other stuff */
    free(bb);
}
```

If `a` becomes `true` then there will be memory leak.

Comment: even `bb` is declared, it does not matter, right? because there's no memory leak.

Comment: @Sato; Memory leak will not come in to play until you allocate memory dynamically. Only declaration will do nothing.

Comment: @Sato in your code, there is no dynamic memory allocation. So, no memory leaks.

Comment: @Sato case B should only be allowed. In C89 this is the case.

Comment: @Sato you are not allocating the memory `bb` is pointing to, so when it comes to memory leaks, there can't be memory leaks: you didn't forget to release the dynamically allocated memory because there is no dynamically allocated memory at all.